# How to echo result of avg function from model to view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to echo the result of the avg() in my query from model to view.
My query is like this

Model:

```
$sql = "SELECT avg(bid_amount) FROM tbl_biddetails ";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query;
```

Controller:

```
 $data['avgbid']=$this->project_model->avgBid();
 $this->load->view('project/projectview',$data);
```

What should be the code in view.?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
$sql = "SELECT avg(bid_amount) AS `avgbid` FROM tbl_biddetails ";
```

In a view just:

```
echo $avgbid;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are outputting the raw SQL data.

Try returning `$query->row_array();` or `$query->row();` in your model.

Your model method would become:

```
$sql = "SELECT avg(bid_amount) avgbid FROM tbl_biddetails";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->row_array();
```

Your controller code:

```
$data['biddetails']=$this->project_model->avgBid();
$this->load->view('project/projectview',$data);
```

Your view code:

```
<?php echo $biddetails['avgbid']; ?>
```

**Edit:**
Completed the answer.